# Docker compose command error when running python

Tags: python, mysql, docker

I am running docker container with

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: ammd_db_mysql
    image: hellojaeho/mysql:test2
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/system_config:/system_config
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    restart: on-failure
    command: python3 /system_config/initialfunc.py
```

which runs image that is built from mysql:5.7 image

```
RUN /bin/sh -c apt-get update -y
RUN /bin/sh -c apt-get install python3 -y
RUN /bin/sh -c apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install mysql-connector
```

when I run the container without `command: python3 /system_config/initialfunc.py`, and run in CLI,

```
>> docker exec -it ammd_db_mysql bin/bash
root@df30c7777f8b:/# python3 /system_config/initialfunc.py
```

the code works well. 
However, when I run the container with the command running this code, I receive this message.

```
ammd_db_mysql  | 1
ammd_db_mysql  | Traceback (most recent call last):
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
ammd_db_mysql  |     self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ammd_db_mysql  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ammd_db_mysql  | 
ammd_db_mysql  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ammd_db_mysql  | 
ammd_db_mysql  | Traceback (most recent call last):
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/system_config/initialfunc.py", line 12, in <module>
ammd_db_mysql  |     con_Mysql = sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="asdf")
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
ammd_db_mysql  |     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
ammd_db_mysql  |     self.connect(**kwargs)
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
ammd_db_mysql  |     self._open_connection()
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
ammd_db_mysql  |     self._socket.open_connection()
ammd_db_mysql  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
ammd_db_mysql  |     errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
ammd_db_mysql  | mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
ammd_db_mysql exited with code 1
```

I searched for the error `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)` and I checked my.cnf file. However, the `bind-address` is already closed.

```
root@28a9ae96446f:/# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# Copyright (c) 2016, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
# :
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

```
root@28a9ae96446f:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d# cat mysqld.cnf
# Copyright (c) 2014, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
# :
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
#log-error      = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

My python code is:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
from mysql.connector.locales.eng import client_error
import os
import subprocess
import crypt
import json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = 1

    print(i);i += 1
    con_Mysql = sql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="asdf")
    print(i);
    i += 1
    cursor = con_Mysql.cursor()
    print(i);
    i += 1
    databases = ("show databases")
    cursor.execute(databases)
    database_list = [databases[0] for (databases) in cursor]
```

Can you help me to find the way to run the python code during the compose up?

#I added the command mentioned as the comment, This is what I got

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: ammd_db_mysql
    image: hellojaeho/mysql:test2
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT}:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/system_config:/system_config
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    restart: on-failure
    command: "apt update && apt install net-tools && netstat -tulnp"
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you are using ${MYSQL_PASSWORD} in your docker-compose file, where does this variable comes from? How do you run your docker-compose to populate these variables in the file?

Comment: Mysql password is set as asdf for now

Comment: @jabbson it is saved in .env file, set as asdf for now. The password matches the code

Comment: Can you verify that mysql actually is running in the container? Exec into the container and run `apt update && apt install net-tools && netstat -tulnp` and show us the output. I think you are overriding the command of the original image (which starts the server) with your own and mysql server doesn't get started at all.

Comment: @jabbson please check my question. I added what I got

Comment: Not exactly, but I did look at the [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/hellojaeho/mysql/test2/images/sha256-7c99ef81256d5cab141183859ec11ba12e29fc8ab39d0f4fa0cf58152c816c27?context=explore). As you can see there is a CMD there that starts the server (mysqld), when you specify your own command in docker-compose file, you override that initial command and mysql server doesn't start.

Comment: So you mean I should add CMD["mysqld"] when I build my custom container?

Comment: my recommendation and i'd say the best practice would be to not mix db and the code in the same container, service decoupling is what makes docker great, but what you are trying to do/build looks like an attempt to create a monolith setup using a container infrastructure.

Comment: You should either not override it or you should make sure to start the database service in your custom container as well.